# Return Statement in Excel VBA

Tags: function, vba, excel, return

So, I'm having some trouble with my VBA coding dealing with return statements, and I don't understand what's causing it.  I made the return statement just like any other that I've ever made, yet it seems that I have a mistake some place.  Can someone tell me where I made the mistake in my function's return statement?

```
Public Function GetPay(Hours, RegHours, OTHours, PayRate, RegPay, OTPay) As Double
    Const MAX_REG_HOURS As Integer = 40
    Dim RT As Double

    If Hours > MAX_REG_HOURS Then
        RegHours = 40
        OTHours = Hours - MAX_REG_HOURS
    Else
        RegHours = Hours
    End If

    RegPay = CDbl(txtPayRate.Text)
    OTPay = CDbl(txtPayRate.Text * 1.5)
    Return RT = (RegPay * RegHours) + (OTHours * OTPay)

End Function
```

Comment: VBA doesn't use `Return`  You should return a value using `GetPay = (RegPay * RegHours) + (OTHours * OTPay)`  ie `[FunctionName] = [ReturnValue]`

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda hoping you hadn't seen my comment so I could delete it in time; I didn't realize that I needed the function name to be the variable that gets sent back, like what you put in your example.  Sorry about that! ^^;

Answer (score 0):

Your function is also overly complex. For example

- `OTHours` is a calculation in the function, so any input is un-necessary as it will be overwritten
- `PayRate` is unused
- `RegPay` and `OTPay` are over-written in the function
- `RegHours` is calculated in the function

As below you could streamline the function calcs, and the inputs

*examples calling the function*

```
Sub B()
MsgBox GetPay(41, 8.1, 12.1)
MsgBox GetPay(44, CDbl(txtPayRate.Text), CDbl(txtPayRate.Text * 1.5))
End Sub
```

*new function*

```
Public Function GetPay(Hours, RegPay, OTPay) As Double
    Dim MAX_REG_HOURS As Long
    Dim RegHours As Double
    Dim OTHours As Double

    MAX_REG_HOURS = 40
    RegHours = Application.Min(Hours, MAX_REG_HOURS)
    If Hours > MAX_REG_HOURS Then OTHours = Hours - MAX_REG_HOURS
    GetPay = (RegPay * RegHours) + (OTHours * OTPay)

End Function
```